# How to add d3 or any module to angular 2 using Angular CLI?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angular

Hi I am new to angular 2. I am trying to inject d3 library to angular 2 using angular cli. I installed d3 using npm install d3. I followed the link

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

I followed the steps

`my angular-cli-build.js.

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
 return new Angular2App(defaults, {
 vendorNpmFiles: [
  'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular2-material/**/*.+(js|css)',
  'd3/**/*.js',
  'ng2-material/**/*.+(js|css)'
]
});
};
```

my index.html

```
 System.config({
    map:{
      "d3Lib":"vendor/d3"
    },
    packages:{
      'd3Lib':{
        defaultExtension:'js',
        map:{
          './d3':'./d3.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

and i included in my component.

When i tried to run ng server it throws d3. module not found. It would be great if some body could help

Comment: can you share system-config file?

Answer (score 3):

Never tried it with `angular2` but I installed my `d3js` to my `ionic2` project like this:

```
npm install @types/d3 --save
```

then you can immediately use it in your components:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Answer (score 1):

My system.config

```
System.config({
    map:{
      '@angular2-material':'vendor/@angular2-material'
    },
    packages:{
      '@angular2-material':{
        map:{
          './button':'./button/button.js',
          './card':'./card/card.js',
          './checkbox':'./checkbox/checkbox.js',
          './input':'./input/input.js',
          './progress-circle':'./progress-circle/progress-circle.js',
          './sidenav':'./sidenav/sidenav.js',
          './toolbar':'./toolbar/toolbar.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  System.config({
    map:{
      "d3Lib":"vendor/d3"
    },
    packages:{
      'd3Lib':{
        defaultExtension:'js',
        map:{
          './d3':'./d3.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
    System.import('main');
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps for adding third party library that worked for me in angular-cli

download the d3 typing from typing and paste it in main and browser folder with in typing folder.

Add reference in corresponding index.ts  files.

Add the map in the system.config (My system.config file).

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map:{
      '@angular2-material' : 'vendor/@angular2-material',
      "d3" : "vendor/d3/d3.js",
      "lodash" : "vendor/lodash/lodash.js",

      "@angular/platform-browser": "vendor/@angular/platform-browser",
      '@angular/core/src/facade': 'vendor/@angular/core/src/facade',
      //'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      'angular2-modal': 'vendor/angular2-modal',
      'angular2-modal/platform-browser': 'vendor/angular2-modal/platform-browser'



    },
    packages:{
      '@angular2-material':{
        map:{
          './button':'./button/button.js',
          './card':'./card/card.js',
          './checkbox':'./checkbox/checkbox.js',
          './input':'./input/input.js',
          './progress-circle':'./progress-circle/progress-circle.js',
          './sidenav':'./sidenav/sidenav.js',
          './toolbar':'./toolbar/toolbar.js',
          './icon':'./icon/icon.js'
        }
      },
      "d3": {
        "defaultExtension": "js"
      },
      "lodash": {
        "defaultExtension": "js"
      },
       '@angular2-material/core': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          format: 'cjs',
          main: 'core'
        },
        '@angular2-material/checkbox': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          format: 'cjs',
          main: 'checkbox'
        },
        '@angular2-material/button': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          format: 'cjs',
          main: 'button'
        },
        '@angular2-material/icon': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          format: 'cjs',
          main: 'icon'
        },
        '@angular2-material/sidenav': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          format: 'cjs',
          main: 'sidenav'
        },
        'vendor/angular2-modal': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'vendor/angular2-modal/platform-browser': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'vendor/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'vendor/angular2-modal/plugins/vex': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'vendor/angular2-modal/plugins/js-native': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        '@angular/core/src/facade': {defaultExtension: 'js'}


    }
  });
  System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
    System.import('main');
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

import it in the corresponding components

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

following the same steps worked for lodash well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to correctly add `d3` to a project with `angular-cli`:

```
npm install d3 --save
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...,
      'd3/build/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

**system-config.js**

```
map['d3'] = 'vendor/d3/build';

packages['d3'] = {
  main: 'd3',
  format: 'global' 
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

See several full working imports at https://github.com/benshope/focus